# How to create dynamic data-table with bootstrap or js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, react-bootstrap-table

I want to add a data-table in my bootstrap template(services Area), the table must have dynamic row adding,editing and searching feature like this.[image]

I want this in my templates services area.

how can i do this ?
 [here is my template](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7D5PeIPD02ydnJqNXdmRnlUczg?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) plugin, it's great, and it has all the features that you want. It's easy to use: just import the CSS and JS and, of course, jQuery. Check the link, and if you need more of an explanation let me know.

Comment: i already tried this but didn't get the ultimate result. can you give a fiddle??    Thank you. #moay

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxr50Lu3/) it is. I maked the fiddle you asked @RiadHossain

Comment: Hi moay,  Wow its looks awesome. but i also want to 'add new row' & 'delete row'  buttons for adding & deleting  rows. it would be more grateful if there is a checkbox in every row.   thank you again.

Comment: OK! So [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dxr50Lu3/5/) I updated the fiddle to add a row manually. but if you want to add a row in database of course you can always do it with the form and get the data and when you get the data on server side you refresh the page and the table would be refresh again. for deletion as well ! and for checkbox that you asked you can just add an extra column with a checkbox in it!

Comment: hey ! i want like this: http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/example.html#manipulation

Comment: It is a good extension that you find... so what is the problem? do you want the ajax call ?!! or do you want to know how you can initialize it? did you read the documantaion? @RiadHossain

Comment: basically i want a table with editing, dynamically adding rows,deleting rows and search features. it doesn't matter what extension we used. i tried some plugins (react-bootstrap-table, data-table, fencygrid, open-js-grid, js-grid atc) but couldn't understand properly. so now i searching for a support to understand one of them. @moay

Comment: what is do you use on server side? do you want to add your data to DB via Ajax or with submit of  form through PHP? @RiadHossain

Comment: want to add my data to DB via Ajax. Like this table....     https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple.html